# Daylight Saving Time start and end dates in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

I'm working on a Rails app where I need to find the Daylight Saving Time start and end dates given a specific offset or timezone.

I basically save in my database the timezone offset received from a user's browser( `"+3"`, `"-5"`) and I want to modify it when it changes because of daylight saving time.

I know `Time` instance variables have the `dst?` and `isdst` methods which return true or false if the date stored in them is in the daylight saving time or not.

```
 > Time.new.isdst
 => true
```

But using this to find the Daylight Saving Time beginning and end dates would take too many resources and I also have to do it for each timezone offset I have.

I would like to know a better way of doing this.

Comment: So looking back at what you are doing a question comes to mind. You are storing just their offset. But is the offset from YOUR time or from UTC? If the offset is UTC then DST doesn't come into play unless they happen to be in a zone that observes DST. Or is the offset the difference from yours, and again, will you know if they are observing DST or not? If your local time changes because of DST and theirs does too, then the offset remains the same.

Comment: I see some possible issues with the way you are doing this. Just because a person's offset puts them in the western time zone of the US, does not tell you if they observe DST. Most of Arizona does not observe DST. Notice I say most, not all. That's why you'd probably want to store the actual time zone as a string.

Comment: Let me give you further details on this. I'm working on a solar calculator that computes the solar elevation angles for each day in a given location on the globe. The app takes the geolocation coordinates, the date and the timezone offset only once. On the server I run a cron job that recomputes the elevation each day on midnight for each timezone( I can have users from New York, London, Moscow and so on).

Comment: Obviously I need to do this for each timezone so basically I my cron job actually runs every 15 minutes, finds the timezones for which the time became 00:00 AM and recomputes everything. Now I store my timezones using the offset I receive from users browser( currently I would get the summer offsets for most of Europe and America). But in the autumn this will change( and the date when it changes is different in various regions). This is the reason I need to find the DST period.

Comment: Comming back to your questions, yes, I currently store only the offset I get from `.getTimezoneOffset()`. I am aware that for certain states in the US and most of the countries in the World there is no DST. However I think that I can solve this problem using the geolocation coordinates I already have. I can get the user's Country/State using them and make the appropriate query.

Comment: OK, so you are getting UTC offset, and you plan on pulling timezone name from geolocation. Does my answer not work for you? As it stands you could use it to take their timezone name and get the start and end dates for their DST if they observe it. I would probably work it into some methods in the model that give your object those methods.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, building on what you've said and [@dhouty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279373/3982562):

You want to be able to feed in an offset and get a set of dates for knowing if there is a DST offset or not. I would recommend ending up with a range made of two DateTime objects, as that is easily used for many purposes in Rails...

```
require 'tzinfo'

def make_dst_range(offset)

  if dst_end = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[offset].tzinfo.current_period.local_end
     dst_start = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[offset].tzinfo.current_period.local_start
     dst_range = dst_start..dst_end
  else
     dst_range = nil
  end

end
```

Now you have a method that can do more than just take an offset thanks to the sugar that comes with ActiveSupport. You can do things like:

```
make_dst_range(-8)
#=> Sun, 08 Mar 2015 03:00:00 +0000..Sun, 01 Nov 2015 02:00:00 +0000

make_dst_range('America/Detroit')
#=> Sun, 08 Mar 2015 03:00:00 +0000..Sun, 01 Nov 2015 02:00:00 +0000

make_dst_range('America/Phoenix')
#=> nil     #returns nil because Phoenix does not observe DST

my_range = make_dst_range(-8)
#=> Sun, 08 Mar 2015 03:00:00 +0000..Sun, 01 Nov 2015 02:00:00 +0000
```

Today happens to be August 29th so:

```
my_range.cover?(Date.today)
  #=> true
my_range.cover?(Date.today + 70)
  #=> false
my_range.first
  #=> Sun, 08 Mar 2015 03:00:00 +0000
  #note that this is a DateTime object. If you want to print it use:
my_range.first.to_s
  #=> "2015-03-08T03:00:00+00:00"
my_range.last.to_s
  #=> "2015-11-01T02:00:00+00:00"
```

ActiveSupport gives you all sorts of goodies for display:

```
my_range.first.to_formatted_s(:short)
  #=> "08 Mar 03:00"
my_range.first.to_formatted_s(:long)
  #=> "March 08, 2015 03:00"
my_range.first.strftime('%B %d %Y')
   #=> "March 08 2015"
```

As you can see it's completely doable with just the offset, but as I said, offset doesn't tell you everything, so you might want to grab their actual time zone and store that as a string since the method will happily accept that string and still give you the date range. Even if you are just getting the time offset between your zone and theirs, you can easily figure correct that to the UTC offset:

```
my_offset = -8
their_offset = -3
utc_offset = my_offset + their_offset
```

Comment: Seems a good suggestion, I'll upvote it, However I will still keep the question open.

Answer (score 6):

What you are probably looking for is [`TZInfo::TimezonePeriod`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/TimezonePeriod). Specifically, the methods `local_start`/`utc_start` and `local_end`/`utc_end`.

Given a timezone offset, you can get a `TZInfo::TimezonePeriod` object with

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-8].tzinfo.current_period
```

Or if you have a timezone name, you can also get a `TZInfo::TimezonePeriod` object with

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['America/Los_Angeles'].tzinfo.current_period
```

Comment: ah, you beat me to it, and with a simpler example.