# Ruby method that takes todays date and if it falls in between DST (daylight savings time) dates, then return the date of that next change

Tags: ruby, date, dst

I am trying to write a method that takes todays date and if the provided date falls in between DST dates for 2018 (DST is true if date is 03/11/18 2:00am and 11/04/18 2:00am), then it would return the date of the next respective DST change.

I actually have no idea how to approach this other than taking the provided date and writing a case statement around it that iterates through the provided date's given year. and each when holds a different year

```
# method to take todays date and if the date falls in between DST dates, 
# then the method will return the date of the next DST change

def dst_date_change(date)
    return case 
        when date.include? ='2018'
            if (date > Time.parse('March 11, 2018 2:00am') &&  (date < Time.parse('November 4, 2018 2:00am'))
    end
        when date.include? ='2019'
            if 

    end
        when date.include? ='2020'
        if
    end
        when date.include? ='2020'
        if  
    end
    else
```

this is what i currently have. clearly unfinished..

Comment: *Date* doesn't include timezone data. Do you mean *Time* or *DateTime*? Or do you want to handle this for a default timezone, since dst differs for different countries? Anyway I'd recommend taking a look at [*Daylight Saving Time start and end dates in Ruby/Rails*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32278565/3982562).

Comment: I am trying to use DateTime, and this needs to be universal as well..

Comment: basically I need to take the system's current DateTime, and i need to see if its closer to one daylight savings time than the other. however, DST varies every year which makes it tricky for me.

Comment: You need to clarify your question (by editing). See my answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have interpreted the question as follows: "Given a date (possibly today's date), if at no time on that day it is DST, return `nil`. Otherwise, return the next date (possibly the same date) that begins as DST and ends as non-DST".

```
require 'date'

def next_dst_date_change(base_date)
  base_date_time = base_date.to_time
  next_date_time = (base_date+1).to_time
  if base_date_time.dst? || next_date_time.dst?
    base_date + 1.step.find { |n| (base_date + n).to_time.dst? == false } - 1
  end
end
```

See [Date#to_time](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-to_time), [Time#dst?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Time.html#method-i-dst-3F), [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step) and [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

Examples

```
d0 = Date.today
  #=> #<Date: 2018-09-24 ((2458386j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
next_dst_date_change(d0)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-11-04 ((2458427j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

d1 = Date.new(2018, 11, 04)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-11-04 ((2458427j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
next_dst_date_change(d0)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-11-04 ((2458427j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

d2 = d0 + 90
  #=> #<Date: 2018-12-23 ((2458476j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
next_dst_date_change(d2)
  #=> nil

d3 = d0 + 365
  #=> #<Date: 2019-09-24 ((2458751j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
next_dst_date_change(d3)
  #=> #<Date: 2019-11-03 ((2458791j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

d4 = Date.new(2018, 3, 10)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-03-10 ((2458188j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
next_dst_date_change(d4)
  #=> nil

d5 = Date.new(2018, 3, 11)
next_dst_date_change(d5)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-11-04 ((2458427j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

To speed things up one could do a binary search to determine the next DST-to-non_DST change date, using [Range#bsearch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-bsearch). I've assumed that DST ends some time before December 1 of each year.

```
def next_dst_date_change(base_date)
  base_date_time = base_date.to_time
  next_date_time = (base_date+1).to_time
  if base_date_time.dst? || next_date_time.dst?
    diff = (Date.new(base_date.year, 12, 1) - base_date).to_i
    base_date + (1..diff).bsearch { |n| !(base_date + n).to_time.dst? } - 1
  end
end
```